# how to restart the Linux Daemon if the daemon process got killed by the user

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, daemon, libc

I have written a Linux Daemon Process in c , now my issue is that
if the user kills the Daemon , the Daemon  must be restarted automatically , how can i implement it inside the Daemon .

Like :: on shutdown event received > restart the Daemon

> Example Scenario
>
> A Daemon is long-lived. Often, a daemon is created at system startup
> and runs until the system is shut down , Lets say for eg: a daemon
> called XXX  , doing important routines like the functions watching for
> specific log files , and if found alert the admin in High security
> apps , if this daemon got killed , it need to be restarted
> automatically

Comment: How is the user killing the daemon?

Comment: @evilotto finding pid there by

Comment: If the user is killing the daemon, they probably don't want it to continue running. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: If you're looking for daemon monitoring, take a look at Ubuntu's upstart system.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using `kill` to shutdown the daemon by pid, you can't do much from inside the daemon to restart it. (because most users read somewhere that you need to always use `kill -9` which is a really bad idea in almost all cases, but they still do it)

If you can guarantee that your users aren't using `kill -9` (and you can't) then you can setup a signal handler to cleanly exit and restart the daemon.

Otherwise your best bet is to have another process restart the daemon when it dies or is killed.  Check out [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or just use a simple shell script:

```
while true; do
    daemon
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong question.   Watchdoging with restart (which is what you're asking about) is a fault tolerance technique.  You don't use fault tolerance to correct for the **willful and intentional** decisions of the human machine operator.  If you don't want the user to kill your process, tell them not to.  If they ignore it, then they have broken their system.  Standard system daemons generally do not respawn, why should yours?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if cron could be a good/safe idea to verify daemon activity.

For instance:

Every 30 minutes launches a script to test if daemon is active.

```
$ */30 * * * * <script to verify daemon activity>
```

the script (pseudocode):

```
if daemon is active
then
    :
else
    restart daemon
fi
```

Comment: adding a cron is good on another context if the service is for ur own machine , but if u want to deploy this service as a module of a product , think what can be done wit out cron